# Angular Kendo Grid : How to get rowIndex on the Kendo-Grid-column-Group?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Kindly suggest how to add the rowIndex value for kendo-grid-column?

I need the rowIndex to be in the Kendo-Grid-column-group so that i could iterate values in 'kendo-grid-column' which is inside 'kendo-grid-column-group'.

Example:

```
<kendo-grid-column-group [width]="500" [locked]="false" *ngFor="let test of categoryArr" title={{test.categoryName}} <GET VALUE AT ROWINDEX HERE>
    <kendo-grid-column field="test.compliant" title="COMPLIant">
        <ng- template kendoGridCellTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
          {{test.compliant}}<USE VALUE OF ROWINDEX HERE>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid-column-group>
```

Comment: Hi, I see this is your first post in SO. To get more chance to get an answer, please provide an example of what you've already did to solve the problem. You would also need to provide a [Minimal reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Actually, i need the rowIndex to be in the Kendo-Grid-column-group so that i could iterate values in 'kendo-grid-column' which is inside 'kendo-grid-column-group'.

Example:

Comment: <kendo-grid-column-group [width]="500" [locked]="false" *ngFor="let test of categoryArr" title={{test.categoryName}}  <GET VALUE AT ROWINDEX HERE  ><kendo-grid-column field="test.compliant" title="COMPLIant" >                   <ng- template  kendoGridCellTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">{{test.compliant}}<USE VALUE OF ROWINDEX HERE></ng-template></kendo-grid-column> </kendo-grid-column-group>